# Get only android device id and save it to an array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am new to bash scripting and I want to write a script that gets only the device id from the bash output when I do:

```
adb devices

Result:-

List of devices attached 
06c3b9270b3fa34c    device
```

So in my array i only need 06c3b9270b3fa34c.

How can i write this in bash?

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. Some combo of `adb`, `tail`, and `awk` will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through grep,

```
adb devices | grep -o '\b[a-f0-9]\+\b'
```

Comment: the first one is good because it shows all the devices connected...the second one only shows one device id

Comment: removed the second one .

Comment: even clearer `adb devices | grep -o '\b[a-f0-9]\{10,\}\b'` assumed the id have atleast 10 digits.

Comment: but no i have like 5 devices...i want to store them in array how can i do that?

Comment: try `adb devices | grep -oP '\b[a-fA-Z0-9]{10,}\b'`. It would be better if you post all the possibilities.

Comment: now the pronlem is it also reads the:-  of... devices... attached .... device...device....device...